# Take a sample from a file or stream?

Tags: stdin, random, streaming, filter

Are there any utilities to filter a sample from a stream on the command-line, e.g.

- print every 100th line of a file or
- print a line of a file out with probability 0.01 or
- via algorithms like [reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling)?

Update: So far I found:

- print every 100th line of a file: `sed -n '0~100p'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple solutions with (GNU) awk:

Every one in 100 (lines with number divisible by 100):

```
do_something | awk 'NR % 100 == 0'
```

or pseudorandomly:

```
do_something | awk 'rand() < 0.01'
```

The numbers will likely not be exactly uniform and it may be necessary to add `BEGIN{ srand() }` to initialize a new seed for each run.

Comment: Thanks, `awk` is really nice. Is there a difference to the shorter: `do_something | awk 'rand() < 0.01'`? Also, to get different lines on each run, the random generate must use a different seed on each run, e.g. like this: `do_something | awk 'BEGIN { srand() }; rand() < 0.01'`.

Comment: Yeah, that should work too, of course. The system I briefly tested on seemed to seed it implicitly, so I promptly forgot about that.

Comment: I think just plain up writing some reservoir sampling algorithm with awk shouldn't be that hard, but I'm a bit worried about the range of the random numbers and getting evenly distributed output if the required numbers are a large fraction of the rng's range.

Answer (score 4):

If you have GNU `sort` on your machine, which supports `-R` (`--random-sort`), you could just

```
$ sort -R myfile | head -n 1000
```

To get 1000 random lines from the file. Does not work on streams though as `sort` needs to read the complete input to do anything.

Comment: Thanks! I used `sort -R` before, just forgot about it for the moment.